# Woocommerce , add_action conditionally

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, add-action

Precisely speaking, I want to change the place of breadcrumbs in category pages.
so I check if it `is_product_category()` and then `remove_action ('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20 )` and `add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 15 )`;

but apparently it's not the solution, since it doesn't work.
**Note** that it adds the action but doesn't remove it and two breadcrumbs are showing on the pages.
Your recommendations are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this



    
  add_action( 'init', 'my_removal_function');
        function my_removal_function() {
        if ( is_product_category() ) {
        remove_action ('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 15 )
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I need the breadcrumb to be added to another hook after then

Comment: ok, try this updated

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the condition before the first hook priority.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'adjust_breadcrumb', 10 );

function adjust_breadcrumb() {

   if ( is_product_category() ) {
       remove_action ('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20 );
       add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 15 )
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I did the exact same too and didn't work :(

Comment: make sure the condition is working.

Comment: yeah, I double-checked, and now is working. thank you again

Comment: hook `adjust_breadcrumb` with `init` and if `init` doesn't work then hook with `wp`